# Identify rows of a nonnegative matrix cannot be a maximum when multiplied by an arbitrary nonnegative vector

Tags: linear-algebra

This is my first post to this site. I am not sure this question is suitable, but here it goes.

I have a matrix where all elements are known to be non-negative. I would like to identify rows of the matrix which cannot be a maximum when multiplied by an arbitrary vector of non negative elements. Perhaps an example would help. For the matrix:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0.1 & 0.1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

The 3rd or 4th rows cannot be larger than all other rows when multiplied by any vector with non-negative elements. The first or second row will be the maximum, or all zero in the degenerate case. I would like an algorithm which can identify such rows. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for the links

Comment: my best thought so far is to take the ith row from the matrix, normalize to length 1, multiply it with the matrix, and test if the ith result is greater than all others. the thought process is a vector "aligned" to a row would most likely result in a maximum. not sure if that can be relied upon though

Comment: Another thought is to frame it geometrically and use a convex hull

Comment: cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039146/simplify-matrix-m-by-eliminating-rows-when-finding-maxmv-where-m-and-v-have-n